# maven2 on ubuntu java home is not defined correctly

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu, hadoop

I have problem to use maven from ubuntu server 13.10 64bit.
I am getting following error (even when I type **mvn -version**):

```
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
     We cannot execute /usr/lib/jvm/jdk//bin/java
```

But when I type **java -version** I get:

```
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

I have no idea where can be the problem, especially because I have used maven without any problems before I've installed hadoop 2.2.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Is this only in shells where hadoop has been run or in all shells right from reboot?

Comment: Thank you, it was only in the shell where hadoop has been run. In the normal user shell it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the Hadoop instructions and/or start up script modifies the JAVA_HOME environment variable in the shell.

Unless this change is made permanent by changing one of the many configuration files - like `$HOME/.profile` - it only influences the shell in which you have observed the problem.